# moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'booktime.main'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

following a book, I created a django project named booktime then an app named main. as I try importing files within the app such as forms.py as in from main import forms the names main and forms are red-underlined, though works in some cases as in views.py where the server runs still
but on running tests file I get no module named 'booktime.main' error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't moved your app files they are being created in the root directory of the project. That means that you have to `import main` and not `booktime.main`. The `booktime.main` is referencing `booktime/main.py` or `booktime/main/__init__.py`.

I suggest you to look how the modules are working in python.
https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Answer (score 0):

you can use within the **main** app `from .main import models # models or forms ...`

**code smart**